# How to insert records using loops

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So this code is basically trying to add 5 cars into the location called 'garage' where the 'car_id' is + 1 so each 'car_id' should be different with the use of a package called 'Package_Store.cars'

For example, car0001 should have a 'car_id' of 1 and car0002 should have a 'car_id' of 2 etc.

I think the issue I am getting is with the 'car_id' as it is not incrementing for car0002 till car0005

This is the error message.

```
00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
```

The code

Answer (score 0):

Your code always inserts the same `CAR_ID`, hence the error.

However, even if you fix it, it'll work in a single-user environment. If two (or more) users run the same code, you're about to hit the same error again because sooner or later they *will* generate the same `MAX + 1` value. What to do? Switch to a **sequence**.

If this is just for your own amusement, then you might e.g.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     car_id   NUMBER;
  3     car_str  VARCHAR2 (10);
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN 1 .. 5
  6     LOOP
  7        SELECT MAX (id) + i
  8          INTO car_id
  9          FROM vehicles
 10         WHERE id < 10;
 11
 12        car_str := 'car' || LPAD (i, 4, '0');
 13
 14        dbms_output.put_line('car_id = ' || car_id ||', car_str = ' || car_str);
 15
 16        Package_Store.cars (car_id, 'garage', car_str, 1, 4);
 17     END LOOP;
 18  END;
 19  /
car_id = 4, car_str = car0001
car_id = 5, car_str = car0002
car_id = 6, car_str = car0003
car_id = 7, car_str = car0004
car_id = 8, car_str = car0005

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefood, thank you for your answer, i wanted to know what this section of code is doing. LPAD (i, 4, '0'); ? thanks

Comment: It left-pads `i` with zeroes, up to 4 characters in length. Basically, it creates 0001, 0002, ..., 0025, ..., 0105, ...

Answer (score 0):

You may also use plain SQL `INSERT`for this simple task

```
insert into  garage
(car_id, location, col1, col2)
select 
rownum car_id, 'car'|| to_char(rownum,'FM0999'),1,4 
from dual 
connect by level <= 5;

select * from garage

    CAR_ID LOCATION         COL1       COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 car0001             1          4
         2 car0002             1          4
         3 car0003             1          4
         4 car0004             1          4
         5 car0005             1          4
```

If the table is not empty, adjust the `INSERT`as follows to use new `id`s and car names

```
insert into  garage
(car_id, location, col1, col2)
with ci as 
(select nvl(max(car_id),0)  car_id from garage)
select 
   car_id+rownum, 'car'|| to_char(car_id+rownum,'FM0999'),1,4 
from ci 
connect by level <= 5;
```